# React : Text and ternary combination not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display class of a div depends on the state of `isAddingVarian` or `isEditingVarian` if both of them is true the class will be `float-right d-one` and if false it will be `float-right`. i know i can do like this

```
<div class={isAddingVarian || isEditingVarian?'float-right d-none':'float-right'}>
```

but i want something like this

```
<div class={"float-right "+isAddingVarian || isEditingVarian?"d-none":''}>
```

how can i do that?

Comment: [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)! `<div className={"float-right " + (isAddingVarian || isEditingVarian?"d-none":'')}>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<div className={`float-right ${isAddingVarian || isEditingVarian? "d-none":''} `}></div>
```

Comment: thank you, it works, but if i want to know more about tha ${ } notation, what keywors i should search?

Comment: @MatiusNugrohoAryanto [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it set up you will never make it to your ternary expression, a string containing chars will always be true, and the || operator returns the first true value.

You just need to rethink the logic and set it up differently.

Comment: nice info njenk